# Which date is my valid departure date with a B2 visa?

Tags: usa, transit-visas, b1-b2-visas

I have a valid B2 visa. The date stamped in my passport says I have until May 9, 2019. When I log onto the I-94 website my admit until date is 09/05/2019.  Which date is accurate?

Comment: When did you enter the US? The only possible confusion I can see is "May 9" vs "September 5". I don't know how the web site displays dates, but if it uses your own locale settings, and your browser is set to `dd/mm/yyyy`, then your browser could display 09/05/2019 for May 9. But, if you consider your entry date, only one of those dates can make sense.

Comment: Please post an image of the admittance stamp in your passport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Every admittance stamp I've had from the US has the date written as, e.g., "Mar 14 2019" (whether hand-written or stamped), presumably precisely to avoid questions about whether 1/2/34 is the first of February or the second of January.